# How to request new banner ad in AdMob Pro?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, admob, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Angular Ionic mobile app.  I recently switched from the old  AdMob cordova plugin (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob) to the AdMob Pro plugin (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro).  I have most everything working, but I can't figure out how to request a new ad.  The old plugin had a function requestAd that would get a new ad and display/replace it in the existing banner.  But using AdMob Pro, the only way I see to get a new ad to display is by using the createBanner function.  This works, but the content shifts up and then back down as the banner is first removed, and then redisplayed with the new ad.  I would like to not have that flicker.

Is there a way in the AdMob Pro cordova plugin to request a new ad without having to remove the current banner and create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the refresh interval in your AdMob portal.

By default the interval is 60 seconds, but you can configure it as you wish.

Comment: @Raymond if the ad is refreshed does that count as a new impression. Also if i refresh the ad in my JS code does that count as a new impression as well?

Comment: yes, if the ad is refreshed, it's counted as a new impression.